# update query with replace and concat

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Am trying to execute below query but its not working as expected.
Please check [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33d925) to get details about question.

Query :

```
update entity_permission 
set permissions = REPLACE(permissions,
                          concat(",",
                                 select id 
                                 from menus 
                                 where url='user_rate_list'
                                ),
                          '') 
where id=0;
```

Explanation :

A table1 have field1 in which values like 1,2,3,4,5,7,8 and I would like to replace it with the blank on some places. I know right now problem with concat is not working with a subquery. but I think it must be working some another way.

So is it possible to achieve using a single query?

Share some good suggestion.

Comment: can you specify more details about your questions and your code and what you want to do ?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: @DipakRathod : I tried my best to share details but let me share some more details with sqlfiddle

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya : Please check description of question now.

Comment: Downvoters, Please share reason of it. IF you have more reputation then it doesnt mean that you can downvote anything.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use [`Group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to get id(s) in a comma separated string from `menus` table where `url = 'user_rate_list'`.
- Now, [Cross join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cross-join/) this [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) with `entity_permission`
  table.
- Utilize [`Replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function to update the values.

Try the following:

```
UPDATE entity_permission AS ep 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT CONCAT(',',GROUP_CONCAT(id)) AS ids 
            FROM menus 
            WHERE url = 'user_rate_list') AS m2 
SET ep.permissions = REPLACE(ep.permissions, m2.ids, '') 
WHERE ep.id = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think here is needs to use concat as well to remove comma before update

Comment: @AnkitDoshi What if the ids are at end or beginning. ?

Comment: There is no possibility of that it's at the beginning because we have default values in starting off menus. But yes if it as ending then also it have a comma before value like here    ,4

Answer (score 0):

try this query :

```sql
update table1 set field1 = REPLACE(field1,(select GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') from table2 where module_url='project1/user_list'),'') where type=0;
```

Edit answer :

assume that :

```
a = (select GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') from table2 where module_url='project1/user_list')
```

then you can use if condition, something like below which covers 4 conditions:

```sql
update table1 set 
    field1 = if(field1 like concat('%,', a, ',%'), 
                REPLACE(field1,concat(',',a,','),''),
                     if(field1 like concat('%,', a),
                        REPLACE(field1,concat(',',a),''),
                            if(field1 like concat(a, ',%'),
                              REPLACE(field1,concat(a,','),''),
                                  REPLACE(field1,concat(a,','),'')
                            )
                      )
              )
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but here single value and more before value i got comma which needs to remove .